# Prove that there exists a unique prime number of the form $n^2 − 1$, where *n* is an integer that is greater than or equal to 2.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

> Prove that there exists a unique prime number of the form $n^2-1$,
>   where *n* is an integer that is greater than or equal to 2.

I know I can factor $n^2-1 = (n-1)(n+1)$. What are my next steps?

Comment: n-1=1 and n+1=p because p is prime and n-1<n+1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existence : $2^2 - 1 = 3$

Uniqueness : Suppose we have a number $n > 2$ with prime number of the form $n^2 - 1$. Then since $n^2 - 1 = (n+1)\cdot (n-1)$, we have $(n+1) > 1$ and $(n-1) > 1$, which means that both of these are factors that are not $1$ and thus $n^2-1$ is not prime.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your explanation.